# I want to delete old posts in a SQL database up to a specific date

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to SQL databases, I would like to know how to delete old posts which I have deleted from my wordpress page. I am now in SQL phpMyAdmin, and I looking at `x2Qhx_posts`, I have tried many orders which I've found in other threads but none is working for me to delete them (I want to delete 28.000 empty posts).

Is there any order to add in SQL code and delete old posts between 2 dates? Let's say between 01/2021 until 06/2022. Any help please?

I tried this :

```
DELETE FROM x2Qhx_posts  
WHERE date < '2022-06-01 08:21:22';
```

and this :

```
DELETE FROM x2Qhx_posts 
WHERE your_date_column < '2022-06-01';
```

Also here I don't understand this: `your_date_column`, what do I need to change here?

Comment: When you tried those attempts, what didn't work as expected?  In those attempts it looks like you don't know the name of the column you want to use, which is certainly going to be a problem.  What columns are in that table?  Which one of those columns are you using for this date value?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: im sorry, how i find the name of the column in in SQL phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand this: your_date_column, what do I need to change here?

`x2Qhx_posts` is a table that will have several columns. One column will hold the post title. Another will hold the post text. Other might hold the author, or tags, categories, etc. One of the columns will hold a timestamp for the post. You need to find the name of the column and put it in place of `your_date_column` in the query.

Comment: im sorry, how i find the name of the column in in SQL phpMyAdmin? sorry im asking all these, thank you